# Javascript Regular expression error in get string between two strings

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have string look like this :

```
"fdsgsgf.signature=xxxxx(bv)"
```

And i want to get `xxxxx`

With : `var testRE = html.match(".signature=(.*)/\(");`

And when i run it i get exception that it's not valid regex.

Any idea why?

Comment: non regex solution.. `html.split("=")[1].split("(")[0]`.. can make better though.

Comment: What is the point of your forward slash?

Comment: Use a regular expression literal instead of a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- You're missing starting slash `/` of your regex
- Instead of `.*` you should better use `[^(]+`
- dot needs to be escaped

Modified code:

```
html.match(/\.signature=([^(]+)/);
```

Comment: Won't this match the slash since it's a string literal? (Didn't downvote btw)

Comment: The `/` isn't missing.  If you use a string then you don't have the slashes.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I am talking from regex perspective since OP tagged question with `regex`

Answer (score 2):

You need to double escape the backslash: `".signature=(.*)/\\("`. This is a valid regex, but it will match the `/` char though. If you don't need it, simply remove it ;)

Comment: Can you give me example?